# Using a particular definition of a field to argue that $0$ commutes with the other elements in the field under multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

My professor defined a field $F$ as a set of elements together with two binary operations $+$ and $\cdot$ such that $F$ forms an commutative group under $+$ (with identity $0$), $F \,  \backslash  \{0\}$ forms an commutative group under $\cdot$, and $F$ is left-distributive.

But because the definition does not state that $F$ is right-distributive, I see no way to argue that $0$ commutes with the other elements in $F$ under multiplication.

Is the definition not correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, this definition is incorrect.  For instance, you could take $F=\{0,1\}$, with $+$ being addition mod $2$, $1\cdot 1=1$, $1\cdot 0=0$, $0\cdot 0=0$, and $0\cdot 1=1$.  It is easy to check that this satisfies all your professor's axioms.

Comment: The definition doesn't explicitly state that F is associative under multiplication; it only states that $F-0$ is associative under multiplication. So even if we add that $F$ is right-distributive, would it still not be the definition of a field?

Comment: If you assume distributivity on both sides, you can prove that $0\cdot x=x\cdot 0=0$ for all $x$ (since $0\cdot x+0\cdot x=(0+0)\cdot x=0\cdot x$, and similarly on the other side).  So associativity even with $0$ is automatic.